# What do I need to use Oracle Database with my application?

Tags: java, database, oracle

What are things that I need to develop an application that uses an Oracle Database?

Actually my confusion is that I have made a schema for my database and if I want to  install my application on another PC, would I have to install **entire Oracle Database**?

This is driving me crazy as probably the size of my application is smaller then the Oracle Database.

I'm new in the programming (practical) field, I am writing the application in JavaSE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you don't have to install the entire db with your application, what all you need just install the `DB` on one place `(DB server)`, then tell your application to connect with that `DB server`:

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@DBhostAddress:1521:user","pass");
```

But if you need to install your application on one PC, your application don't have to be used in multiple `PC's` then you need to install the `DB` beside your application.

if its just stand alone application, you may want to think in using different alternatives than `DB`, such as `files`.

I know that the DB is a professional way dealing with data, but you maybe still want to look at some alternatives, anyway.

Or you may go with an Derby java embedded DB or any java supported embedded `DB's`.

Comment: thanks for **your response** i know this and if i want to   install my **builded application** that has every thing as u have listed above Do i have to include database installer along with my application installer ? being more specific is there amy light weight oracle database (package) that can provide backend support for my application to run database ?

Comment: @dip, Yea i got your question, please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks @salah your help is more then any thing ! If i want to used my application in multiple pcs then should i have to use servers like tomcat, glassfish etc. Actually im little confuse between DBMS and Servers (oracle and glassfish or tomcat). Again thanks in advance.

Comment: @dip, any time, and what i meant by DB server is DBMS like when you install oracle suite, you just installed the DB server. Tomcat glassfish are web applications servers not a db servers. they are responsible to deploy and run the web application.

Comment: Also you need the thin driver in your application.